# I want to disable discord bot commands in dms but I keep getting an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my discord reject code:

```
 client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel && msg.author.id !== "828093594098204702") {
        const Reject = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#FF0000")
            .setTitle('Error')
            .setDescription('This command can only be used in the server.')
        msg.author.send(Reject);
    
    
    }
    })
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
 const member = msg.guild.members.cache.get(msg.author.id);
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of null
    at Client.<anonymous>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is this line `const member = msg.guild.members.cache.get(msg.author.id)` coming from?

Answer (score 2):

**(v13)**

I know, that you are using messages, but if you will you'll change your mind and will start using slash commands, use `if (!interaction.guild) return;`, this will disable slash commands in DMS. Also you can add `interaction.followUp` to return a message.

Answer (score 1):

```
client.on("message", message => {
    
    if(message.author.bot
    || message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    // your code here

}
```

this is what I use to filter out bots and dms.